# Replace certain characters by html element

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string like this: `var text = "sdasd #ELEMENT1# asdasd #ELEMENT2#";` and I have to replace all the `#ELEMENT-X#` for a button and you would get something like this `sdasd <button>ELEMENT1</button> asdasd <button>ELEMENT2</button>`.

I have a little regex that returns an array of index of every `#`

```
var regexp = /\#/g;
var match, matches = [];
while ((match = regexp.exec(text)) != null) {
    matches.push(match.index);
}
console.log(matches);
```

then I tried to replace the # for the  and  if # is odd or even, but it doesn't work as I was expected

```
var count=0;
var countPos=0;
var tempText='';
  for(var j=0; j<text.length; j++){
        for(var k=0; k<matches.length; k++){    
            if(j===matches[k]) {
                if(count%2 !== 0){
                    tempText = text.substr(countPos,j);
                    finalText += tempText.replace("%", '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs fx-remove" data-var-token="[%XPTO%]" contenteditable="false">')
                }else{
                    tempText = text.substr(countPos,j);
                    finalText += tempText.replace("%","</button>");
                }
                finalText += text.substr(countPos,j);
                count++;

              countPos = j;
            }


        }
    }

       console.log('--------- '+finalText+' ---------------');
```

My finalText returns a lot more text then the original text.

What is the best approach to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
var text = "sdasd #ELEMENT1# asdasd #ELEMENT2#";

text = text.replace(/#(.*?)#/g, '<button>$1</button>');
snippet.log(text)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```